# pgfplot: groupplots -- how old?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to reproduce some examples from the pgfplot documentation, but `\usepgflibrary{groupplots}` does not succeed, while `shapes` does. In the documentation I can't find a hint if this feature is too new for my distribution, I have `texlive-full` in version `2009-15` ... is this too old?

The error message is pretty clear:

```
! I can't find file `pgflibrarygroupplots.code.tex'.
<argument> ...input pgflibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                              \catcode `\@ =\csname pgf@...
l.5 \usepgflibrary{groupplots}
```

But as I'm working collaborative with colleagues, installing a more recent version is not a solution.

**EDIT**

This is the code I try to compile.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group name=my plots,
    group size=2 by 2,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left
},height=4cm, width=4cm]
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
\nextgroupplot
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I get:

```
! I can't find file `pgflibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex'.
<argument> ...input pgflibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                              \catcode `\@ =\csname pgf@...
l.4 \usepgflibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is simply that `groupplots` is a library from the `pgfplots` package. Thus it needs to be *used* as:

```
\usepgflibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
% or
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
```

For easy reference in the answer, the `groupplots` package was added to the `pgfplots` tree around October 2009. The 1.4 version was released on: 7-14-2010. I am not entirely sure about the first release version where `groupplots` was used.

Comment: Thank you for the hint (corrected code above), but does not work. `usepgfplotslibrary` results in an `Undefined control sequence` while the other method tells me `I can't find file 'pgflibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex'` ... seems to be a version issue.

Comment: @wal-o-mat Try and see if the groupplots file exists in the directory:`tex/generic/pgfplots/libs`. It is named with groupplots. If it does not exists you dont have it available. Then you need to install the version from sourceforge.net

Comment: For reference it was added to the pgfplots tree around october 2009. So you may have an outdated version. :(

Comment: Yes, it's not there. It's a pity, but fixing it on my machine will render the repo uncompileable for the others. So I manually place my plots. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with MikTeX 2.9 with `pgfplots` installed in 2013 trying to reproduce [the same example from the gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).

In `tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/` I had a file called `tikzlibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex`, not `pgflibrarypgfplots.groupplots.code.tex`.

Hence I had to change the imports from:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
```

... in the original example to just ...

```
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
```

After that it worked fine.